# My discord.js bot is sending 2 embedded messages but it's only supposed to send one with a single command

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

[image: Discord Example]

```
else {
            
            if(timeout - (Date.now() - cooldowns[message.author.id].daily) > 0) {
                
                let time = ms(timeout - (Date.now() - cooldowns[message.author.id].daily));

                embed.setColor("ff0000");
                embed.setDescription(`**You already collected your daily reward!** ❌`);
                embed.addField(`Collect again in`, `**${time.hours}h ${time.minutes}m ${time.seconds}s ⏳`);
                console.log(embed);
                return message.channel.send(embed);
                
                
            }
```

This is what I currently have for a daily money system. I asked the person who showed me how to write this and he said it looks all good. I have no idea why it's writing duplicate embedded messages after a single command. I made sure not to have multiple instances of the bot running in case that was the issue. I am using discord.js and am open to all suggestions.

Comment: Try removing console.log(embed) and ** from time

Comment: I used the console.log(embed) as troubleshooting to see whether the code was actually giving 2 responses. I checked, and this doesn't change anything or the way the command reacts. Since the ** are in a text area and not formatted as an input, nothing changed when they are removed, thanks for the input though. :)

Comment: @SoullessCookie Can you share complete file via github or gist ? I want to see where did you define embed ?

Comment: @Vipulw I have a Sourcebin for it if that works? This is the entire daily command and response file:      https://sourceb.in/f2fb35af62

Comment: Everythings look good, strange ! Did you try debugging ?

Comment: @Vipulw Visual Studio Code says there are no bugs at all and I haven't gotten a single error... or is that not what you mean by debugging?